# Is "pulled down" ok instead of "took down"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There was hanging a collection of ancient weapons on the wall. I **pulled down** a spear and looked at it.

Is "pulled down" ok instead of "took down"?

Is it optional whether to put "down" before or after "a spear"?

Answer (score 2):

"Pulled down" implies some force was applied, and usually means that there was some resistance. For example, you pull down a roller blind.

"Took down" is far more gentle.

"Grabbed" is an alternative which implies hurriedly taking, but does not imply any resistance.

Comment: I would also add that if something is mounted/hung on a wall, "pulled down" says that you actually *pulled* on it *downwards*, and it then came off, which implies, since most ways of mounting things aren't intended to work that way, that you probably broke whatever was holding it, or ripped it off the wall, etc.  "took down" implies that you took the necessary care to remove it in the intended way (and presumably did not damage anything in the process).